# Get POST Data from TIdHTTPProxyServer

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I'm trying to get the post data from TIdHTTPProxyServer, using OnHTTPBeforeCommand or OnHTTPDocument events but all is useless.
How can I do that?

BTW, I'm using Indy 10, but other solutions (with synapse, for example) will be cool.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` data is not available in the `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event, as it has not been read from the socket yet.  Only the HTTP headers are available in that event.

`POST` data is available in the `OnHTTPDocument` event, but only under the following conditions:

1. the `POST` request uses a non-zero `Content-Length` header (as `TIdHTTPProxyServer` does not yet support the `Transfer-Encoding` header to handle compressed/chunked HTTP messages).
2. the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.TransferMode` property is `tmFullDocument` when the `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event exits.  By default, the `TransferMode` is set to the same value as the `TIdHTTPProxyServer.DefaultTransferMode` property, which is `tmFullDocument` by default.
3. the client sends the `POST` request directly to `TIdHTTPProxyServer`, specifying a full URL as the target.  If the client instead sends a `CONNECT` request directly to `TIdHTTPProxyServer` to establish a tunnel to the target server and then sends the `POST` request through the tunnel to the target server (for instance, when establishing SSL sessions for HTTPS requests), `TIdHTTPProxyServer` does not expose access to that data.  It is a straight pass-through from one socket to another.

Comment: The only way to intercept the data in #3 is to attach an Intercept component to the `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Intercept` property, but then you have to parse the raw HTTP (and possibly SSL) data manually as it flows through the Intercept.

Comment: Did you mean setting TIdServerCompressionIntercept in OnHTTPBeforeCommand?

Comment: Not `TIdServerCompressionIntercept`, I was thinking more of `TIdConnectionIntercept` instead. But yes, you could use `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` to look at the request details stored in the current Context and decide whether to intercept its connection's subsequent data or not.

Comment: I tried the following code, but still no results: `procedure TForm1.IdConnectionIntercept1Send(ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept;
  var ABuffer: TArray<System.Byte>);
begin
  mmo1.Lines.Insert(0, BytesToString(ABuffer))
end;

procedure TForm1.DoHTTPConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Intercept := IdConnectionIntercept1;
end;

procedure TForm1.DoHTTPDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Intercept := nil;
end;`

Comment: "No results" means what exactly? Is the `OnSend` event being called at all? Is any data appearing in the `TMemo`? Remember that Indy servers are multi-threaded, so you cannot directly access UI components in server events, you have to synchronize with the UI thread, such as with the `TIdSync`/`TIdNotify` classes. Also, the data in `OnSend` event is arbitrary and you are not specifying any encoding to `BytesToString()`, so it might be failing to decode the data into a proper String. Try specifying `Indy8BitEncoding` as the encoding, or use `BytesToStringRaw()` instead.

Comment: `OnSend` is ok, event is triggered. No result means no POST data at all. [Here](http://pastebin.com/Bq8Q0MMc) is some `TMemo`output. I tried different encodings, but it's always the same.

Comment: That log is not showing any of the HTTP requests, only HTTP responses. Which makes sense if you are only using the `OnSend` event, which is triggered for data sent by Indy to the client. To log data received by Indy from the client, use the `OnReceive` event instead.

Comment: But POST Data should be in OnSend event, isn't it?

Comment: Data sent by the client to `TIdHTTPProxyServer` will be in the `OnReceive` event.  Data sent by `TIdHTTPServer` to the client will be in the `OnSent` event.

Comment: In `OnReceive` it looks like this: [http://pastebin.ru/6iBzjheZ](http://pastebin.ru/6iBzjheZ)